# merge and plus arrays with same key

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this for loop that gets the data from each user from the matchlistResponsestats object. When the for loop is finish, I have around 90 arrays that look like this `["username", kills, assists, deaths]`

I want to merge and plus the data from the arrays into each username. Also, I would like to add a new value at the end of the array with the number of arrays that were merged into the username

```
for (var i = 0; i < matchArrayTotalPlayer; i++) {
            if(matchlistplayers[i].username === username) {

              const matchlistplayerkills = matchlistResponsestats.players[i].kills
              const matchlistplayerheadshots = matchlistResponsestats.players[i].headshots
              const matchlistplayerdeaths = matchlistResponsestats.players[i].deaths
              const matchlistplayerusername = matchlistResponsestats.players[i].username
              console.log(matchlistResponsestats)
              var playermatchstats = [matchlistplayerusername, matchlistplayerkills, matchlistplayerheadshots, matchlistplayerdeaths]
            }
```

The output from the for loop (playermatchstats)  looks like this

```
["dJadebisi", 17, 5, 19], ["softarlugnt", 16, 8, 22], ["pruttstjert", 1, 0, 5], ["dJadebisi", 16, 4, 8], ["pruttstjert", 10, 0, 15], ["softarlugnt", 9, 1, 20]...
```

and I want an output that looks like this:

```
["dJadebisi", 33, 9, 27, 2],["softarlugnt", 25, 9, 42, 2], ["pruttstjert", 11, 0, 20, 2]
```

Can someone give me a hint in the right direction?

Comment: ur question is not clear

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reduce` to achieve this

```
matchArrayTotalPlayer.reduce( (acc, cur) => {
 const name = cur[0]
 let el = acc.find(item => item[0] === name)

 if (!el) {
  el = [name, 0, 0, 0]
  acc.push(el)
 }

 el[1] += cur[1]
 el[2] += cur[2]
 el[3] += cur[3]
 el[4] ++

 return acc
}, [])
```